# duda ultimo id insertado (mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedure

Hola buenos dias a todos.

Necesito hacer un *insert* a una tabla X e inmediatamente hacer un *insert* en una tabla Xx. El *insert* a la primer tabla funciona sin problemas, pero la particularidad que el segundo insert tiene como llave el ID que generó el primer *insert*, por lo cual se me ocurre que antes del segundo *insert* debo obtener el ID que genero el primer *insert*.

Estuve viendo que *mysql* tiene una función (last_insert_id) pero no entendí muy bien el uso. Deberia ir en la *query* en la que hago el *insert*? o debo crear un método (un *select*) con esta función?

Trabajo con *c#* y *mysql* y para los *insert* hago uso de procedimientos almacenados.

Codigo del boton guardar:

```
        private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string respuesta = "";

            //validamos los campos obligatorios
            if (this.txtCodFuncionario.Text == string.Empty || this.txtIDHorario.Text == string.Empty ||
                this.txtCodPaciente.Text == string.Empty
                )
            {
                mensajeError("Faltan datos por ingresar, favor verificar");
                error.SetError(txtCodPaciente, "Debe seleccionar o ingresar el Codigo del Paciente");
                error.SetError(txtIDHorario, "Debe seleccionar un horario de atención");
                error.SetError(txtCodFuncionario, "Debe seleccionar o ingresar el Codigo del profesional");

            }
            else
            {
                if (this.isNuevo)
                {

                    //PRIMER INSERT
                    respuesta = negociosCitas.insertar(

                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCodPaciente.Text), //ok
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCodFuncionario.Text),
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIDHorario.Text),
                       this.dtpFecha.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                       Convert.ToString(this.cmbEstado.SelectedItem),
                       this.lblEstadoPago.Text
                        );

                        //RECUPERAR EL ID DE LA CITA INSERTADA
                        this.txtIDCita.Text=

                        //SEGUNDO INSERT
                    /*respuesta = negociosPagos.insertar(
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.lblIDMedioPAGO.Text),
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIDCita.Text), ACA DEBERIA IR EL ULTIMO ID INSERTADO
                       this.dtpFecha.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"),
                       Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtMontoPago.Text),
                       this.txtDetallePago.Text);*/

                }
                else
                {
                    respuesta = negociosCitas.editar(
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIDCita.Text),
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCodPaciente.Text), //ok
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCodFuncionario.Text),
                       Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIDHorario.Text),
                       this.dtpFecha.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                        Convert.ToString(this.cmbEstado.SelectedItem)
                        );
                }

                if (respuesta.Equals("OK"))
                {
                    if (this.isNuevo)
                    {
                        this.mensajeOK("REGISTRO INSERTADO CON EXITO EN LA BASE DE DATOS");
                        //ACA PODRIA LLAMAR A LA ACTUALZIACION DEL ESTADO DE LA CITA YA QUE LA RESPUESTA DEL METODO INSERTAR FUE OK
                        //negociosCitas.editarEstadoPago(Convert.ToInt32(txtIDCita.Text), "Pagado");  

                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.mensajeOK("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CON EXITO");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.mensajeError(respuesta);
                }

                this.isNuevo = false;
                this.isEditar = false;
                this.botones();
                this.limpiarControles();
                //this.cargarGrilla();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Saludos a todos, leo sus comentarios

Comment: justo después del insert tendrías que poner **SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();** y usar ese dato para el siguiente insert

Comment: hola @Dibort, la linea que me comentas deberia ir en mi procedimiento almacenado del primer insert?

Comment: La respuesta de Dibort es correcta, creo que formulaste un poco mas tu pregunta, para ponernos un poco mas en contexto, podrías detallar que tecnologías estas utilizando?

Comment: hola @Christian, estoy usando C#, mysql y trabajando con una estructura a 3 capas (negocios, presetnacion y datos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` si te quieres asegurar que estás obteniendo realmente el valor que acabas de insertar. Y sí, lo podrías poner directamente en el siguiente insert, por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES ('cosa1', 'cosa2', 'cosa3');
INSERT INTO table2 (campoz, idanterior) VALUES ('campoz', last_insert_id());
```

[Referencia en el manual MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: gracias estimado, me aclaro la logica del funcionamiento, pero en mi caso tengo el codigo en un button (copie el codigo que uso) y no podria pasar el last_insert_id, NECESITARIA recuperarlo y ponerlo en un label y de ahi pasarselo a la segunda consulta